# Prevent yum from checking for updates when a new package is going to be installed

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum

Whenever I want to install a new package with *yum*, It first checks for updates. Is there a way to stop it from checking for updates each time a package is going to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define "checking for updates" ... do you mean that it checks if the repo. metadata is valid? You can alter that with the metadata_expire variable (see man yum.conf), but in general I would not recommend running against old data.

If you mean the obsoletes checks, you can turn that off ... but again, that's not recommended.

Comment: I changed it to _30d_ but it still checks for metadata before an installation. Is it needed to reload the config file? If yes, how?

Comment: yum has some checks so that it'll ignore the timeout and always check if yum.conf changes ... but apart from that "yum install" should only reload the metadata every 30 days (with your configuration).